# jboss duplicate resource [(\"core-service\" => \"vault\")]"

Tags: jboss

So, my question is in theme.

Firstly, I added into EAP 6 my vault with command

```
/core-service=vault:add(vault-options=[("KEYSTORE_URL" => "PATH_TO_KEYSTORE"), ("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" => "MASKED_PASSWORD"), ("KEYSTORE_ALIAS" => "ALIAS"), ("SALT" => "SALT"),("ITERATION_COUNT" => "ITERATION_COUNT"), ("ENC_FILE_DIR" => "ENC_FILE_DIR")])
```

But I got mistake and try do the same command with correct fields, but get exception

```
{"outcome" => "failed",
"failure-description" => "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [(\"core-service\" => \"vault\")]",
"rolled-back" => true
}
```

In standalone.xml I deleted any vault but still got that error.

How to fix it?

Or How can I find that in my web-console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I had to stop JBoss and after that remove

```
<vault>...</vault>
```

elements from standalone.xml.

After that start JBoss and again do action from management cli. There is noone error happen